# Branching OWIN pipeline based on hostname

Tags: c#, owin, katana

With OWIN (specifically Katana) it is possible to configure applications to different branches. For example:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/branch1", branch1 => branch1.UseMiddlewareA());
        app.Map("/branch2", branch2 => branch2.UseMiddlewareB());
        app.UseDefaultMiddleware();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve the same thing based on host name rather than route path? So for exampl, say you have `www.mydomain.com/blog` configured with `app.Map("/blog", blog => blog.UseBlog());` Instead of this, you want to use `blog.mydomain.com`.  Both `blog.mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com` point to the same web application, but for the `blog` sub-domain, I want it to use a different app configuration within the OWIN pipeline.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm confident you could; the MVC pipelines branch considerably based upon request details. However, in this particular case I'd recommend a _much_ simpler approach such as adding two sites to IIS and mapping the hosts to the respective Http Bindings. Is that not an option here?

Comment: It could be an option to use separate sites, and I may go down that route. One of the possible reasons for this is to have a single application as a host which can have components added to it, but I want to manage them as a single application for singular deployment.

Comment: If you wanted to keep to a single site but plan to host on IIS, then URL Rewrites might be an option too, though it's not something I'm particularly familiar with. I would expect them to be able to convert `foo.example.com` to `example.com/foo` allowing you to use MVC areas, for which there are plenty of modular example articles around for.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this with MapWhen.
http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin/Mapping/MapWhenExtensions.cs